# Solution to differential equation: $f''[x]g'[x]-f'[x]g''[x]=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How can I solve a differential equation of this type?

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f[x]}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial g[x]}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f[x]}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 g[x]}{\partial x^2}=0
$$

I believe the following notation is equivalent:

$$
f''[x]g'[x]-f'[x]g''[x]=0
$$

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{f'}{g'}\right) = \frac{f'' g' - f' g''}{g'^2} $$
so your equation says $f'/g'$ is constant (unless $g' = 0$, which would also satisfy the equation).  Thus we get either $f = a g + b$ for constants $a,b$, or $g = c$ for constant $c$.

Comment: If $g=\overline{f}$; the complex conjugate of $f$, can the equation still work?

Comment: If $f = a \overline{f} + b$, and $|a| \ne 1$,  then $f$ must be constant.  If $|a|=1$, the values of $f$ can lie on a line in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $g'(x)$ is not the zero function, we divide both sides by $(g'(x))^2$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}) = 0$$

Hence,

$$f'(x) = cg'(x)$$

$$\implies f(x) = cg(x) + d$$

This is the most you can get with the information provided

Answer (score 0):

$$f''[x]g'[x]-f'[x]g''[x]=0$$
You can rewrite it as:
$$\dfrac {f''[x]}{f'[x]}=\dfrac {g''[x]  }{g'[x]}$$
$$(\ln f'[x])'=(\ln g'[x])'$$
And integrate.